Intuition for stationary distribution of Markov Chains
Why aren't the matrix elements of the stationary distribution equal to weighted average of incoming probability?
For example, take this Markov chain:

In matrix form $\boldsymbol{P} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0.2 & 0.8 \\ 0.5 & 0 & 0.5 \\ 0.1 & 0.9 & 0  \end{pmatrix}$, then to find the stationary distribution I use the matrix equation $\boldsymbol{\pi P} = \boldsymbol{\pi}$, then I use the fact that for two matricies to be equal each element must be the same, then I normalized $\boldsymbol{\pi}$ and I got:
$\boldsymbol{\pi} = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{55}{237} & \frac{92}{237} & \frac{30}{79} \\ \frac{55}{237} & \frac{92}{237} & \frac{30}{79} \\ \frac{55}{237} & \frac{92}{237} & \frac{30}{79}  \end{pmatrix}$
The intuition behind each row having the same values makes sense as in the long run it doesn't matter if you initially started in the first, second or third state (I think if the stationary distribution equation were $\boldsymbol{P \pi} = \boldsymbol{\pi}$ then the matrix would be transposed).
But my question is why doesn't $\pi _{11}, \pi _{21}, \pi _{31} = \frac{1}{5}$ since 0.6 probability go into state 1 and in total from each state comes out 1 probability, so in total 3, shouldn't it be the weighted average $\frac{0.6}{3} = \frac{1}{5}$? If it's not the weighted average, maybe it is something else?

The probability coming into State 1 is less than $0.6$: it is $0.5$ times the probability of being in State 2 plus $0.1$ times the probability of being in State 3.  So you get $\pi_1=0.5\pi_2+0.8\pi_3$ and similarly $\pi_2=0.2\pi_1+0.9\pi_3$ and $\pi_3=0.8\pi_2+0.5\pi_2$.  Solving these as simultaneous equations (you only need two of them since they are linearly dependent) together with $\pi_1+\pi_2+\pi_3=1$ gives the stable distribution where the probability coming in equals the probability going out of each state.

@Henry Ahh, although, for example, the incoming probabilties for $pi _1$ are 0.5 from $\pi _2$ and 0.1 from $\pi _3$, the probabilities of being in states $\pi _2$ and $\pi _3$ are different, so it isn't as simple as summing the incoming probabilites. Thanks!
